# Infinite product involving prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

In an article I am reading the author states that the product  over all prime numbers $p$

$$\Pi_p(1-p^{-p}),$$

is about $.722$. Why?

I believe this should be related to the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: The partial products approach the limit very rapidly, so a computation of the first few terms will do the job. Is it a tail estimate that you are looking for?

Comment: 0.721990234 after four terms (to $p=7$) and essentially does not change after that as subsequent terms get smaller by at least a factor of $1000$ for each prime.